# How to convert LocalDateTime to Date ignored timezone?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I want to subtract hours from LocalDateTime and convert to Date, but my way always gets around the TimeZone factor.

```
Date fromDate = request.getFromDate();
LocalDateTime reqFromDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(fromDate.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
Date fromDateArg = Date.from(reqFromDate.minusHours(11).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

E.g:

> 2020-01-01T20:00 >> I want exactly: 2020-01-01T9:00 date that independent with timezone.

Timezone included can affect the result that passes to the query as a bind parameter. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Why you want to convert to Date? Date is legacy, you should not use it anymore

Comment: Are you looking out for timezone or timeformat ? As per your expected result , you need the time in 12hr format instead of 24hr format. Also what is your input date and it's format?

Comment: Date is one of my bind parameters in JPA query. @YCF_L

Comment: please refer to this https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: @Gundamaiah: Any format. But time-independent in any timezone (Any local machine calls my API return the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking the impossible. A `LocalDateTime` does not in itself define a point in time. A `Date` on the other hand *is* a point int time (despite the class name). So how could a conversion be possible? Which conversion do you want?

To add a little depth, a `LocalDateTime` is a date and time of day without time zone. The `Local` in some class names in java.time means “without offset or time zone”. To interpret a `LocalDateTime` into a point in time, you first need to interpret in some time zone, leaving room for a span of about 26 hours.

A `Date` cannot represent `2020-01-01T09:00` independently of time zone. Never. It can represent a point in time that in some time zone would be rendered as `2020-01-01T09:00`.

You are correct that time zone makes a difference for the result you get. That’s exactly why we need it for the conversion.

You said in a comment that you need it for a JPA bind parameter. I wonder if that’s necessary. To pass a date and time that is independent of time zone to your JPA query, pass a `LocalDateTime`. A modern JPA implementation should accept that.

If there is no way to pass a modern class to JPA, a conversion using the default time zone of your JVM (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`) will probably give you what you want. It’s common to interpret a `Date` in this time zone.

Comment: I'll try. Thank you for the nice explanation. @Ole V.V

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "OffsetDateTime"? Is a date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system,